# How to apply master page to all pages, sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have A portal in SP 2010 which contains a lot of sites and sub-sites.
To a specific site and all its' sub-sites I want to apply the same master-page, I did it from the Share-Point designer 2010.
The problem is that the pages in the sub-sites doesn't take the mater page, do I have to change them manually?
TIA.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via Visual Studio by creating a Site Scoped Feature and then adding the Event Receiver.  In it, override the FeatureActivated to apply customer master page to every site in a site collection.  Here is a snippet i use:

```
var siteCollection = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
if (siteCollection == null)
    return;
foreach (SPWeb site in siteCollection.AllWebs)
{
    using (site)
    {
            site.CustomMasterUrl = webAppRelativePath +
                     "_catalogs/masterpage/custommasterpage.master";
            site.SiteLogoUrl = webAppRelativePath +
                     "Style Library/Images/logo.gif";
            site.Update();
        }
    }
```

Alterantively you could modify this on-demand to use SharePoint PowerShell interface:

```
$site = get-spsite "http://sps2010/sitecoll"
$site.AllWebs | foreach-object { `
             $_.CustomMasterUrl = "_catalogs/masterpage/custommasterpage.master";
             $_.SiteLogoUrl = "Style Library/Images/logo.gif";
             $_.Update();
}
```